# Create an array of UNIQUE 5-digit random numbers in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, random, arraylist, unique

I have the following code generating 5-digit random numbers and adding them to an ArrayList. These numbers however must be unique ids.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    int id = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * 89999) + 10000);
    idArr.add(id);
}
```

I'm trying to work out how I could check to see if the number was already in the array before adding it but I can't get my head around the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an `array`. That way you would just need to use [`ArrayList#contains(obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method to test whether the `id` is already in the `ArrayList` or not.

Or, you can just work with a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), which will work faster with its [`HashSet#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

Comment: Thanks Rohit - the contains method was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an (Array)List, use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

```
Set<Integer> set = ...;
while (set.size() < myArr.length) {
  set.add(yourRandomNumber);
}
```

Comment: Minor comment: the OP was asking for "unique 5-digit numbers", not "5 unique numbers". The number `5` there should be `myArr.length`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Set` of the numbers. E.g.:

```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
while(intSet.size() < myArr.length) {
    intSet.add(getNextRandomInt());
}
```

Then yo can do anything with that `Set`.

So, if you need an array, just call:

```
Integer[] intArray = intSet.toArray(new Integer[myArr.length]);
```

or, if you need an `ArrayList` or `int[]` array:

```
// ArrayList:
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.addAll(intSet);

// int[] array:
int[] intArray = new int[myArr.length];
for( int i = 0; i<intArray.length; ++i) {
    intArray[i] = int.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything which involves looping until you find enough unique random numbers is never guaranteed to complete. It's possible, if extremely unlikely, that the random number generator will never output enough unique numbers in a reasonable amount of time.

(I know this will never happen **in practice**, but it's a **theoretical** possibility.)

A safe alternative is to choose one random number, and then increment it in a loop until you have enough numbers.

```
int n = new Random().nextInt(89999 - myArr.length) + 10000;
for (int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    idArr.add(n++);
}
```